# Coda 2 column width limitation/delimiter

Tags: coda

I'd love to be able to use Coda 2 as my primary IDE, but my workspace has a 80-character line limitation standard. Is there a way to add a limitation or some sort of visible representation of the 80-character limit in Coda 2?